# WiFi access-point in BeagleBone

Tags: wifi, dhcp, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack, access-point

I am trying to start WiFi access point on my Beaglebone Black.
There is no brige. I just want to connect to AP from my phone for setting up some custom configs.

I installed hostapd success, and edit the following config files: 
I am using Angstrom Linux (kernel 3.8)

etc/network/interfaces

```
#When auto_bridge is "yes" then init.script makes bridge itself
#when aut_bridge is "no" then init.script start /etc/network/bridge
AUTO_BRIDGE=yes

STP_ENABLE=no
FD_TIMER=0
GCINT_TIMER=0

#BR0_USE_DHCP=no
#BR0_IPADDR=192.168.0.50/24

IPV4_FORWARD_ENABLE=yes
START_IPTABLES=yes

VLAN_START=yes

WLAN_ENABLED=yes
WLAN_FORCEIP=no
WLAN_IN_BR0=yes
WLAN_USE_DHCP=yes
WLAN_IPADDR=192.168.0.5/24
WLAN_MACADDR=00006c576976
WLAN_BURST=no

WLAN_USE_UNCHECKED_MIBS=no
```

etc/udhcpd.conf

```
start           192.168.0.10   #default: 192.168.0.20
end             192.168.0.15   #default: 192.168.0.254

# The interface that udhcpd will use

interface       wlan0            #default: eth0

opt     dns     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
option  subnet  255.255.255.0
opt     router  192.168.0.5
option  lease   864000
```

etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
# Basic configuration

interface=wlan0
ssid=MyNet
channel=1
#bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=aaaaaaaaaa
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Hardware configuration

driver=rtl871xdrv
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
device_name=RTL8188CU
manufacturer=Realtek
```

After this I write in connamd line:

```
sh-4.2# udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
sh-4.2# hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
drv->ifindex=4
l2_sock_recv==l2_sock_xmit=0x0x63648
+rtl871x_sta_deauth_ops, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is deauth, reason=2
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:0f:13:76:1d:6b and ssid 'MyNet'
rtl871x_set_wps_assoc_resp_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_beacon_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_probe_resp_ie
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_beacon_ops
rtl871x_set_hidden_ssid_ops
+rtl871x_get_sta_wpaie, 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec is sta's address
```

Ater this I tried to connect to AP from my phone.
See please the follwing log of hostapd:

```
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec IEEE 802.11: associated
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
+rtl871x_send_eapol
+rtl871x_send_eapol
rtl871x_set_key_ops
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec RADIUS: starting accounting session 52AC6766-00000000
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
+rtl871x_sta_remove_ops, 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec is sta address removed
+rtl871x_get_sta_wpaie, 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec is sta's address
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec IEEE 802.11: associated
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
+rtl871x_send_eapol
+rtl871x_send_eapol
rtl871x_set_key_ops
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec RADIUS: starting accounting session 52AC6766-00000001
wlan0: STA 00:a0:c6:fe:5e:ec WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

In my phone I see messages:

```
Connecting
Autentification
Getting ip address

Connecting
Autentification
Getting ip address

Connecting
Autentification
Getting ip address
```

My phone cannot to connect to AP as a result.
I think that problem in udhcpd.

Please help me to find a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can refer to http://fleshandmachines.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/wifi-acces-point-on-beaglebone-with-dhcp/

To sum up it says that angstrom not support what u want to do. This solution use debian.